Find the size of the radius of the nth circle.
In the figure shown, calculate the size of the radius of the nth circle.
(Answer:$\frac{R}{n^2+2}$)

I calculated the radius of the first two circles. How to extrapolate this resolution to other rays?
$(\frac{R}{2}+r_1)^2=(\frac{R}{2})^2+(R-r_1)^2 \implies Rr_1=R^2-2Rr_1  \therefore r_1=\frac{R}{3}
(\frac{R}{2}+r_1)^2=(\frac{R}{2}+r_2)^2+(r_1+r_2)^2 \implies Rr_1=Rr_2+2r_2^2 +2r_1r_2 
\frac{R^2}{3}=Rr_2+2r_2^2+\frac{2Rr_2}{3} \implies R^2=5Rr_2+6r_2^2
\therefore:R=-r_2\vee R=6r_2 \implies r_2=\frac{R}{6}...$
$Similarly:\frac{R}{11},\frac{R}{18},\frac{R}{27}$
$\therefore \boxed{r_n = \frac{R}{n^2+2}}$


This question is similar to: Epic Circles - Numberphile.

How did you prove that the triangles you draw in the bottom are right triangles (which you use in order to apply Pythagoras' theorem)? I don't see how to prove it but it feels that one can prove that the center of the circunference of radius R and two consecutive circules of the series above it form a right triangle. And thus your prove would work in general, I think!

What I was trying above does not work, I was just checking on Geogebra and only the centers of the first two circles form a right triangle with the center of the circunference of radius $R$.

Descartes' circle theorem seems relevant.

In December 1960, John Satterly wrote an article in The Mathematical Gazette addressing this exact same subject in volume 44, number 350.
For the full article, see: Satterly, John. "The Sequence of Touching Circles." The Mathematical Gazette, vol. 44, no. 350, Dec. 1960, pp. 263-268. The Mathematical Association, https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614892. Accessed 30 June 2024.


Fig. 1 shows an outer semicircle of radius $R$ and two inner
semicircles of radii $a$ and $b$ such that $R=a+b$. Denote these
semicircles by $R, A, B$, their centres by $S, A, B$ respectively and
the right hand end of the common diametrical line by $O$.A sequence of
touching circles is inscribed in the region between the large
semicircle and the two smaller semicircles. Number the circles in this
sequence $1,2,3---n---$ and denote their centres by $C, C_2-C_n-$,
their radii by $c, c_2--c_n--$ and the coordinates of these centres by
$X_1 Y_1, X_2 Y_2, \cdots--X_n Y_n--$ these last being measured from
axes $S X, S Y$.$\mathbf{C}_1$. To get $c_1$ we see that it is the
common intersection of three circles, viz a circle of centre $S$ and
radius $R-c_1$., a circle of centre $A$ and radius $a+c_1$, and a
circle of centre $B$ and radius $b+c_1$.The equations of these circles
are$$\begin{aligned}x^2+y^2 & =\left(R-c_1\right)^2 \\(x-R-a)^2+y^2 &
 =\left(a+c_1\right)^2 \\(x+a)^2+y^2 & =\left(b+c_1\right)^2\end{aligned}$$The solution of these equations gives$$\begin{aligned}c_1 & =R a(R-a) /\left(R^2-R a+a^2\right)=R a b
 /\left(R^2-R a+a^2\right) \\X_1 & =R^2(R-2 a) /\left(R^2-R
 a+a^2\right) \\Y_1 & \left.=2 R a(R-a) / R^2-R a+a^2\right)=2
 c_1\end{aligned}$$The common denominator $R^2-R a+a^2$ may also be
written $R^2-R b+b^2, R a+b^2, R b+a^2, a^2+a b+b^2$, symmetrical in
$a$ and $b$. Having now found $C_1, X_1, Y_1$, intersecting circles
may be used to find $C_2, X_2, Y_2$. The algebra however becomes
complicated and it is easier to use Soddy's Theorem on Touching
circles and its useful corollary which states that if a circle be
described to touch three touching circles of radii $a, b, c$, its
radius $r$ is given by$$r=a b c /\left[(b c+c a+a b) \pm 2\{(a b
> c)(a+b+c)\}^{\frac{1}{2}}\right] \tag{4}$$If the positive sign of the
square root is taken $r$ is positive and it is the radius of the
circle which lies within the common enclosure, and all contacts are
interior contacts. If the negative sign of the square root is taken
$r$ is negative and it is the radius of the circle which encloses the
three circles, i.e., the radius of the circle which is touched
internally by the three circles; and must be taken as negative in
calculations where if three of $r, a, b, c$ are given the fourth is to
be found. $\mathbf{C}_n$. By use of Eq. (4) with circles $R, A,
> B$ we find$$c_1=R a b /\left(R a+b^2\right) \text { as obtained above,
 }$$and by use of circles $R, A, C_1$, we find $c_2=R a b /\left(R
 a+2^2 b^2\right)$ and by use of circles $R, A, C_2$ we find $c_3=R a b
 /\left(R a+3^2 b^2\right)$ and so on. Therefore in general$$c_n=R a b
 /\left(R a+n^2 b^2\right).$$

Corollary. When $a = b = R/2$, the formula simplifies:
$$
c_n = \frac{R b^2}{b(R + n^2 b)} = \frac{R}{n^2 + 2}.
$$
